# Jquery, подключенный несколько раз

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, господа.

Вопрос будет двоякий: как не наступать на грабли и что делать, если наступил )

1. Есть JQuery, вписываем его в шаблон html страницы - все супер. Но, допустим, JQuery мы подключили несколько раз. Ну, знаете, сейчас полно кода, страницы друг в друга инклюдятся. С PHP файлами все просто `include_once`, а вот javascript, как быть с ним?
2. Тут прошу разрушить миф: если подключить JQuery более 1 раза, скрипты будут работать некорректно. Сам такого не замечал, но буду признателен за 1 любой пример сего безобразия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В таком случае вам лучше сделать файл, который вы будете подключать только один раз (у меня, например, это header.php) и в нем подключить jquery. Тогда вы избежите повторного подключения.
2. Если будет подключено несколько разных версий - тогда да, по поводу подключения одной версии несколько раз - не знаю.

Comment: Утверждать не стану, но считаю, что даже если разные версии будут - ничего не произойдет (необычного), т.к. функции интерпретатор сообщит о том, что функции уже определены и продолжит работу со старыми (или переопределяться?).

Answer (score 1):

По логике: должно работать, главное - чтобы новые функции библиотеки не затерлись старыми. ИМХО: лучше, конечно, не практиковать такое, нагрузка там, все дела.